# Rounding numbers and Changing Factor based on size (math/algorithm issue)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, rounding, hammer.js

I am currently writing a tool that allows a user to change a value by pinching their screen. I am using Hammer.js to catch the pinch event and I am using the `scale` property of the event to determine the factor of which to change the value.

The following code illustrates how I am increasing and decreasing the value based on the pinch:

```
var value = 10;
var scale = false;
var previous_scale = false;

pinch.on("pinch", function(e){
    // Only proceed is it is not the final touch
    // The final touch has a scale of (0)
    if(e.isFinal===false){
        // Only proceed if the previous scale has been defined
        if(previous_scale!==false){
            // Calculate the difference in scales
            scale = e.scale-previous_scale;
            previous_scale = e.scale;
            if(scale>0){
                value = Math.round(value+(1+(scale*100)));
                value = value>=4000 ? 4000 : value;
            }else{
                value = Math.round(value-(1+(Math.abs(scale)*100)));
                value = value<=10 ? 10 : value;
            }
            console.log(value);
        }else{
            previous_scale = e.scale;
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is, I would like the `value` to do the following:

- When `value` is less than 30, increment by 1 for each scale
- When `value` is less than 60, increment by 5 for each scale
- When `value` is less than 200, increment by 10 for each scale
- When `value` is less than 1000, increment by 50 for each scale
- When `value` is less than 2500, increment by 100 for each scale
- When `value` is less than 5000, increment by 500 for each scale

I have tried to achieve the above by inserting the following:

```
if(radius>2000){
    radius = 500*Math.round(radius/500);
}else if(radius>1000){
    radius = 100*Math.round(radius/100);
}else if(radius>300){
    radius = 50*Math.round(radius/50);
}else if(radius>50){
    radius = 10*Math.round(radius/10);
}
```

This hasn't worked as it is only rounding the numbers, I actually need to increase the factor as the numbers get larger.

Can anyone advise on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As the `scale`var is already a delta, that seems pretty straightforward:

```
if( value >= 2500 ) {
    value += 500 * scale;
}
else if( value >= 1000 ) {
    value += 100 * scale;
}
else if( value >= 200 ) {
    value += 50 * scale;
}
else if( value >= 60 ) {
    value += 10 * scale;
}
else if( value >= 30 ) {
    value += 5 * scale;
}
else {
    value += scale;
}

if( value < 0 ) {
    value = 0;
}
if( value >= 5000 ) {
    value = 5000;
}
```

(assuming a cap at `value` = 5000).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need the rounded number anyway (correct me if I'm wrong), so as there are a limited number of possible values you can use a linear scale modified by the pinch event to address as an index to the desired values:

```
var value = 10;
var scale = 10;
var previous_scale = false;

pinch.on("pinch", function(e){
    // Only proceed is it is not the final touch
    // The final touch has a scale of (0)
    if(e.isFinal===false) {
    scale = Math.round(scale * e.scale);
        if ( scale < 0 ) {
            // lower bound
            value = 0;
        } else if ( scale < 31 ) {
            // 0-30 increment of 1        --> 31 values
        value = scale;
        } else if ( scale < 37 ) {
            // 35-60 increment of 5       -->  6 values
            value = 30 + (scale - 30) * 5;
        } else if ( scale < 51 ) {
            // 70-200 increment of 10     --> 14 values
            value = 60 + (scale - 36) * 10;
        } else if ( scale < 67 ) {
            // 250-1000 increment of 50   --> 16 values
            value = 200 + (scale - 50) * 50;
        } else if ( scale < 82 ) {        
            // 1100-2500 increment of 100 --> 15 values
            value = 1000 + (scale - 66) * 100;
        } else if ( scale < 87 ) {
            // 3000-5000 increment of 500 -->  5 values
            value = 2500 + (scale - 81) * 500;
        } else {
            // higher limit 
            value = 5000;
        }
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Please, tell me if this is somewhere near to what you were thinking.